# When creating a new VueJS instance, does it clone all the child elements in it's specified root element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

Take this HTML for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        var trace = console.log.bind(console);
        var vm, $$$ = {};

        $(document).ready(function() {
            vm = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    allInfos: '',
                    allErrors: ''
                }
            });

            initElements();

            popupInfo('Testing box-info...');

            setTimeout(function() {
                popupError('Testing box-error...');
            }, 3000)
        });

        function initElements() {
            $$$.boxInfo = $('.box-info');
            $$$.boxError = $('.box-error');

            TweenMax.set('.box', {alpha: 0});
        }

        function popupInfo(msg) {
            vm.allInfos = msg;
            popupBox($$$.boxInfo);
        }

        function popupError(msg) {
            vm.allErrors = msg;
            popupBox($$$.boxError);
        }

        function popupBox(box) {
            TweenMax.fromTo(
                    box,
                    0.5,
                    {alpha:0},
                    {alpha:1, onComplete: function() {
                        setTimeout(hideInfo.bind(box), 1000);
                    }}
            );
        }

        function hideInfo() {
            TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {alpha: 0});
        }

    </script>
    <style>

        .box-info { background: #88f; }
        .box-error { background: #d44; }
        .box {
            display: inline-block;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 9999;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        #header {
            position: relative;
            top: 50px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <div class="box box-info" v-html="allInfos"></div>
        <div class="box box-error" v-html="allErrors"></div>
        <div id="header">
            <h3>Testing VueJS instantiation + element references issue.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I move the order of `initElements()` so that it happens **BEFORE** the VueJS instance is created, like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initElements(); // <----- Moved this line

    vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            allInfos: '',
            allErrors: ''
        }
    });

    popupInfo('Testing box-info...');

    setTimeout(function() {
        popupError('Testing box-error...');
    }, 3000)
});
```

...it breaks the references to the boxes HTML elements (the calls to `TweenMax` are operating on the detached boxes from the DOM hierarchy).

Why does this happen? And is there a way to preserve the existing elements in the `#app` DIV container?